# I am using Op.not in sequilize and i want to use or in between same fields

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

**I am using LEFT OUTER JOIN in sequilize and i want to use or in between profilePicture : 'public/uploads/default/default-male.png' and profilePicture :'public/uploads/default/default-female.png'**

```
return models.Users.findAll({
        where: {userType:'engineer'},
        include: [
            { model: models.CandidateDetails, as: "CandidateDetails",
            where: { [Op.not]: 
                [{ profilePicture : 'public/uploads/default/default-male.png'}, {profilePicture :'public/uploads/default/default-female.png'}
                                ]}, required: false }
            ]
      });
```

**In this iam getting output**

```
`CandidateDetails`.`user_id` AND NOT (`CandidateDetails`.`profile_picture` = 'public/uploads/default/default-male.png' AND `CandidateDetails`.`profile_picture` LIKE 'public/uploads/default/default-female.png')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `Op.or` inside `Op.not` like this:

```
where: { [Op.not]: 
    { [Or.or]: [{ profilePicture : 'public/uploads/default/default-male.png'}, { profilePicture :'public/uploads/default/default-female.png' }
                                ]
    }},
    required: false
}
```

Comment: Did you get the desired SQL query?